# Job Scheduler interval gets called way too infrequent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler

My App schedules a JobScheduler with a periodic interval of 60 seconds:

```
val service = ComponentName(packageName, MonitorService::class.java.name)
val job = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, service)
            .setPeriodic(interval) // interval is 60*1000
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .build()
jobScheduler.schedule(job)
```

I am aware of the fact, that the Android OS optimizes the job scheduler, therefor it will never be scheduled exactly, but with like 2~3 minutes later. I verify this behaviour on my own device (HTC One M8 with Android 6.0).

On many (various) other devices that interval is **much** more infrequent (like once/twice per hour only).

How can I fix that? Is the Job Scheduler maybe not the correct API for my use case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `JobScheduler` minimum period is 15 minutes on newer versions of Android. [See `getMinPeriodMillis()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#getMinPeriodMillis()).

In terms of your "use case", doing anything every minute is horrible for battery life. Users have complained **very loudly** about this, and so Google continues to take steps to prevent apps from doing this. For example, Doze mode and app standby on Android 6.0+ will cause your jobs to run very infrequently, on the order of once an hour or less.

Comment: If the app is whitelisted (ignores battery optimisation), does `getMinPeriodMillis()` still return 15mins?

Comment: @JohnM.: I have not tried that. If I were a betting man, I would say "yes", as that is most likely hardcoded per Android OS version.